# Generate properties like in DB Scaffold

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, scaffolding

I use scaffold to generate models by database. I need to generate property name like in database but i would like to have Model names in pascal case like by default. How to do that?

I know that there is `--use-database-names` attribute , but model names also changed

DB

```
TABLE [ak_Table] (ModifON)
```

Now generated this file

```
class AkTable {
  public int ModifOn { get; set; }
}
```

But required

```
class AkTable {
  public int ModifON { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What EF and .NET version are you using?

Comment: .Net 6 and EF Core 6

Comment: Linq2Db is your final answer.